# Cout the last result only?

Tags: c++

I want to cout the last result only instead of all the results, for explain here's my code i tried it but didn't work:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string boo="blablab";
    int count=0;
    int b=0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < boo.size(); i++)
    {
        while (boo[i] == 'a')
        {
            count+=i+1;
            if(count>b) b=count;
            cout<<<<"a="<<b<<"\n";;
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

instead of resulting:
   A=3
   A=9
i want it to result:
   A=9

Comment: What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: Can you at least fix the indentation, please? And explain what it's supposed to do in the first place.

Comment: it count the character a orders together

Comment: `while ... break` - that's just an `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the `cout` outside the `for` loop, like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < boo.size(); i++)
{

while (boo[i] == 'a')
{
 count+=i+1;
 if(count>b)
 b=count;
// cout<<<<"a="<<b<<"\n";; //remove from here
break;
}}
//add here
cout<<<<"a="<<b<<"\n";;
```

Comment: Also, consider splitting the code that computes stuff from code that prints stuff out. That separation will make this sort of thing easier.